# tsconfig compilerOptions "module": "system" not working

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, angular, systemjs

In the angular2 5 min tutorial they use "system" as the module in the tsconfig. I have systemjs as a node_module but when trying to start my server I get `System is not defined`, from the first line of the compile js-file which looks like this: 
`System.register(['http', 'express', './config/index', 'path'], function(exports_1) {`

Why is `System` undefined even though I have it as a node dependency?

I was trying to change it to commonjs, then the compiled js looks much simpler. But then I get errors in the angular application.

What am I missing in order for it to work with SystemJs?

**Edit**

I think I was bad at explaining my problem. When changing from importing modules into my server.ts file "javascript style" (`var http = require('http');`) to I guess "typescript style" (`import * as http from 'http';`) I start getting the error specified above. When doing it javascript style the compiled js looks just the same as the ts (`var http = require('http');`) however when doing it "typescript style" it gets compiled with modules being imported using System (the line of code specified above). So i'm getting this error when trying to start the node server and not in the browser.

I tried changing the compilerOption "module" to "commonjs" instead of "system" in tsconfig.json, doing that causes errors in the browser ([this error](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5999), only the solutions doesn't seem to fit) for some weird reason so i figured i'd try with "system". But then I ran into the problem of not have `System` defined. So how do I get access to System when starting the node server?

Comment: Have you included it in your index.html?

Comment: Yes, but i get this error while trying to run the node server

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing reference to system.js in your index.html. Angular is meant to be run by browsers so its not enough to have it as node dependency, browser will not load it automatically. And of course do not try to run angular application on server side in node.js. What you want to do on server-side (node.js) is to run some web server that will serve content to the browser (http-server, lite-server, etc). And then open your index.html served by web server in browser that in turn will run angular2 application using system.js for module loading.

If you do have system.js referenced in index.html and you are not trying to run it on node.js server side - make sure the path is correct and it does get loaded - by using development tools of any modern browser.

Comment: Se my edit. I can't start the node server because of this error. systemjs works fine in the browser

Comment: System.js can handle modules in commonjs format without any problems. So you can stick to commonjs. Regarding the error you refer to - do you have all libraries/shims linked in index.html exactly like it suggests in 5min tutorial? I assume also that you have tried running it with latest chrome just to verify that its not a legacy issue.

Comment: Yes, I figure changing to commonjs changes the structure of my angular components and that is why that part is not working. Following the 5min tutorial you're expected to use systemjs for handling modules and the bootstrapping. The problem is when I set "system" is that my node server typescript files are also compiled "system"-style, and I get my error because there is no System the running the node server. My question is basically that. How come I don't have System defined when running the node server? And how do I get it? All things related to the browser doesn't seem relevant..

Comment: Why do you expect node.js to use System.js module loader for loading modules? It has its own way of loading modules by using 'require' function. Therefore all javascript that will be trying to load modules by any other means will fail in node,js server environment. See here about module loading in node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: When specifying what module to compile my typescript in the tsconfig I choose "system" since that's what is used in the tutorial. When my node server is compiled same tsconfig is used and all module imports are compiled to use system. Can you change what module system to be used in different parts of the typescript project?

Comment: As far as I am aware - no. You can either stick to commonjs (I have angular2 project compiled with commonjs and running without problems). Or (and I think its preferable) separate server and client implementations in two separate projects if they are anything but very basic applications.